# Not able to fetch comments from SharePoint user profile social database

Tags: sharepoint, csom

I want to fetch comments entered using SocialCommentControl from user profile social database. I tried following snippet in Managed CSOM API but could not succeed. Any help will greatly appreciated.

```
    System.Net.NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("domain\\useracc", "pass@word1");
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://testsitecollection/"); clientContext.Credentials = cred;PersonProperties owner = new PeopleManager(clientContext).GetPropertiesFor("domain\\useracc");
MicrofeedManager mgr = new MicrofeedManager(clientContext); 
clientContext.Load(mgr, f => f.CurrentUser); 
clientContext.Load(owner); 
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
MicrofeedRetrievalOptions optn = new MicrofeedRetrievalOptions(); 
optn.ContentOnly = true; 
optn.IncludedTypes = MicroBlogType.All; 
optn.ResultSortOrder = MicrofeedSortOrder.CreatedTime; 
optn.NewerThan = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2);
ClientResult<MicrofeedThreadCollection> res = mgr.GetMyConsolidatedFeed(optn); 
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```